# What is a "remote gateway" in FortiClient?

Tags: fortinet, remote

Apologies in advance, I am a complete noob to this and I am just barely dipping my toes into networking for the first time. I think I have a basic understanding of how most aspects work in concept, but I'm getting a little lost when trying to actually apply that knowledge in real scenarios.

**Goal**
I wanted to set up a VPN on my desktop computer so that I could remotely connect to it over the Internet from my laptop. I decided to use Windows Remote Desktop Connection, but to connect two computers that aren't on the same network using that software I need to set up a VPN for my laptop to connect to.

I knew I had a free copy of FortiClient available to me through my university. I downloaded & installed it, and then tried to set up an SSL-VPN. However, one of the fields it asked for was the "Remote Gateway"... and I have no idea what that is. Searching online for a definition just brings up articles about a server software called "Remote Desktop Gateway Server", which I believe is different? (although please let me know if I'm wrong!)

**Question**
So all I am wondering is what the "Remote Gateway" that FortiClient is asking for?

Again, I am completely new to this so I would appreciate it if you're gentle because I'm very willing to learn, but I'm just still starting out. :) Thanks!

[image: The field in the client]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FQDN of where you want the client to connect to. Like if your company VPN is vpn.companydomain.com, you would put that in there.  You could also just put the IP address behind the FQDN if you know it, but that would result in a certificate warning, in which case you'd want to check the box at the bottom to ignore certificate warnings.

Comment: Oh, understood. So FortiClient is just the client-side software for actually connecting to the VPN like @Zac67 said, and this is where that IP address/Domain name would go. Understood! It works now!

Comment: @Guy Correct.  Cool.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

The *remote gateway* is your Fortigate unit - FortiClient is the client-side software for a VPN tunnel, the other side is a Fortigate router. You can't use FortiClient to tunnel across two PCs.

Comment: Oh, okay, I had that switched around in my head and thought FortiClient could be used to host the VPN, not just connect to it. Got it working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> When you have SSL VPN you should have accessible `FQDN` or `IP
>   address`. That is a remote gateway which you need to put it on here.

Otherwise you are not able to connect from outside.

> Connection name can be any name which you want.

SSL is Certificate based authentication and Prompt on login will prompt certificate at each login time. You can same your login credentials but it is not secure at all. But you cannot use it for connect two different Computers. You need to use Fortigate firewall as a VPN server.